# How to get rid of an overflow in my code?

Tags: java

I needed to create a code that inputs 4 numbers and outputs the product and average of these numbers. I needed to output them both as integers and decimals. However, to compute the product the second time (with decimals) I am supposed to input values like 100000, 200000, 300000, 500000, which causes an overflow and I'm not sure how to fix it. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int num1;
      int num2;
      int num3;
      int num4;
      double numProduct;
      double numAverage;
  
      num1 = scnr.nextInt();
      num2 = scnr.nextInt();
      num3 = scnr.nextInt();
      num4 = scnr.nextInt();
      numProduct = num1 * num2 * num3 * num4;
      numAverage = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) * 0.25;
  
      System.out.print((int)numProduct + " ");
      System.out.println((int)numAverage);
      System.out.printf("%.3f ", numProduct);
      System.out.printf("%.3f", numAverage);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please paste code as text.

Comment: Please read [ask] and post a [mcve].  Youe screen shot does not even show any code.

Comment: If you are multiplying or taking the average of 4 digits, there won't be any overflow.  Do you *really* mean overflow?  Perhaps you should describe what you are trying to fix (with an example) so that we can figure out what you mean.

Comment: Or perhaps you have said "digits" where you mean "numbers".  A digit (in decimal) is a number in the range 0 to 9.  Either way, your problem **as written** is incorrectly stated.

Comment: @pszrux I edited my question so it shows the code now! Thank you!

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'm sorry, I didn't realize the picture of my code didn't work. I edited my question and put my code in it! Thank you!

Comment: @StephenC I'm sorry for the confusion, I fixed my question so hopefully, it makes more sense now! Thank you!

Comment: *"I didn't realize the picture of my code didn't work."* - The real issue is that the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) says this:  "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.".  There are a number of very good reasons for this rule, and it is basically non-negotiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually casting the first `num1` in your mulitplication will do it.

```
numProduct = (double) num1 * num2 * num3 * num4;
```

The problem was that the multiplication of the 4 `int`s is done in `int`, and then the final result is cast into a `double` on assignment to `numProduct`. You need to cast the first `int` into a `double` in the multiplication in order to force whole multiplication to be done in `double`.

Comment: Actually, if the 4 input values are digits (i.e. numbers in the range 0 to 9) **as the question states**, then overflow is not possible.  So there won't be any overflow and it doesn't matter if the computation is done using `int` or `double` arithmetic.

Comment: @kamion It worked! Thank you so much! Have a great rest of your evening! :)

Comment: @florez_05 can you please accept my answer?